# List information about a facebook user

Tags: php, facebook

What i'm trying to do:

1. User goes on my website.
2. User logins via facebook
3. The website lists information about the user like so:

Name: John simpsons

Hobby: Footbal, Computers

Favorite tv shows: King of Queens, How i met your mother

Favorite movie: Inception

Birthday: 1983, 12 April

Current city: New york

Etc: etc

What i got right now:

```
<?php
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>

   <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>
```

And this writes the user name like so:

Name: John Simpsons

But i would like it to write down more information like i said above, like user hoobies, favorite moves etc.

Any idea on how i would do that? I've been trying to google it but can't find anything about it.

Comment: What permissions does your Facebook app request?  Is the user granting those permissions?

Comment: I figured the app will request every permission it needs to post this information.